# Datagridview add row form behind don't increment CurrentRowIndex

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have found a bug on datagridview (vb.net), if I add a row from code, the value of DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index is always 0.
If I add row manualy (with mouse) the value of DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index is right.

I have a function that add some rows from code and I have implement DataGridView1_CellValueChanged and I check if the first cell in selected row is empty or not, but this check always first row.
I've found this bug in this link, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/datagridview-event-rowsadded-doesnt-show-the-corre/2270 and microsoft don't want to fix it.

I can use a simple variable boolean for fix this bug, but maybe someone can help me for resolve definitly this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bug. Microsoft even stated as much in the report you linked to. "By design" means not a bug.

The `CurrentRow` is the row that contains the `CurrentCell` and that is the cell that contains the caret. When the user adds a row in the UI, it is assumed that they will want to edit that row, so the grid moves the caret to the first cell in that row. When you add a row in code, there's no specific expectation that the user is going to want to edit that row because it wasn't the user who added it, so the caret stays where it is.

If you want a newly added row to be the `CurrentRow` then you need to assign a cell in that row to the `CurrentCell` property of the grid, e.g.

```vb
Dim newRowIndex = myDataGridView.Rows.Add()
Dim newRow = myDataGridView.Rows(newRowIndex)
Dim firstNewCell = newRow.Cells(0)

myDataGridView.CurrentCell = firstNewCell
```

You would probably put code like that into a method and then call that method whenever you wanted to add a row.

Comment: Hello jmcilhinney, your code help me some much. Thanks.